# Rename a Scheduled Task Using PowerShell 4.0

Tags: powershell

Is there an amendment to the following script which would allow me to rename a Scheduled Task?

```
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe"
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName "YourTaskName" -Action $Action
```

Thanks

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/219930/134295

Comment: That would explain why after a solid hour of googling returned nothing but export/import posts.

I all ready have an excel file which will build a bat file to export and import, but as I am now getting into PS Scripting I was hoping for a solution using it.

Thanks @AnsgarWiechers